# Why was my posted answer deleted instead of just advise to reword in a comment?

Tags: support, status-declined, deleted-answers

A moderator who goes by 'Philipp' deleted [my answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20087/why-is-greeces-debt-considered-a-problem-but-not-us-debt-which-is-much-higher/20121#20121) to a question of Greek debt vs US debt claiming it was a rant.  My answer was not a rant.  This was just his opinion.  He probably did  not like my answer because it exposed the ugly truth of how neoliberal colonial policies are imposed on countries against the best interests of the citizens and future generations of citizens in these countries.

My answer applies perfectly.  Even if it didn't he can express his opinion as a comment, not delete my answer.  That is malicious censorship.

Please undo this deletion.  Thank you.

Comment: Protip: your case will be stronger if you leave out the personal insults and such.

Comment: There are no insults.

Comment: @bytebuster ok, I converted to a question.  Now please undo the deletion.

Comment: Assuming malicious intent *is* insulting.

Answer (score 8):

I can understand why it's deleted.  Even if an answer kinda sorta answers the question, if its main focus is to speak at length about some other issue that's tangentially related to the question, then I usually don't consider it to be an answer.  It's more of a blog post (or as some people say, "rant") masquerading as an answer.

The question was asking why Greece's debt is a bigger deal than the US's debt.  It wasn't asking about how Greece got in debt.

Comment: I am sorry you couldn't see how the question was answered.  Did you bother to look up the book reference.  Again, if you think it's a blog post or a rant, that is just your opinion and leave a comment as to how it could be better worded.  Censorship by deletion is going too far and violates me.  The rant call is an arbitrary judgement.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for editing the title.

> Why was my posted answer deleted…?

As Philipp said in their [comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20087/why-is-greeces-debt-considered-a-problem-but-not-us-debt-which-is-much-higher/20121#comment73675_20121), the post does not answer the question, *"Why is Greece's debt considered a problem but not US debt […]?"*
Instead, it answers the question like *"Do the crooked imperialists take over Greece by forcing it borrow money instead of feeding itself?"*

In some cases, if your post contained direct answer to the question, you could *also* expand on "crooked capitalists" — but only if it helped your argument and only if it were backed with credible evidence. Be careful, however, as this may appear thin ice, and some users may be tempted to suggest removal the superfluous section of your post.

> … instead of just advise to reword in a comment?

The point of the deletion is:

1. to avoid the flamewar of denials in comments (by hiding/locking it), and
2. to let the OP improve their post (while hidden) and prepare for its undeletion.

So, the deletion **is** an advice to reword your post and then flag it for Mod's attention.

Comment: I can't edit it once it is deleted.  It's locked from editing. If you really think about it,

Comment: @0tyranny0poverty, you [should be able](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6347/187133) to edit your deleted post, unless it is **self**-deleted, which is not the case. In my understanding, the fundamental concept of Stack Exchange is to allow you improve your content, and I will be greatly surprised if it were changed since the old times. The permissions used to be [buggy sometimes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128813/187133), but always fixed quickly. If you are totally sure you can't edit it, I would suggest firing a question at [meta.se].

Answer (score 1):

How to make your question not a rant.

Cut

> Taking away the property or rights of persons without their consent is theft. No one has the right to put another person or persons into debt without their consent. Such unauthorized debt is immoral, unethical, and should be illegal by international law.

This is an opinion that is unrelated to the question of why the US debt is considered fine, but the Greek debt is not.

Your idea that global capitalism is conspiring to use debt as a weapon of neo-colonialism is a very contentious one. Don't phrase your answer as 'This is the way it is,' phrase it as, 'This is the way Anthony Perkins believes it is.'  Quote the book you're citing. See [this answer](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/a-full-and-objective-description-of-good-faith/3043#3043) for more ideas on how to phrase your answer in a way that won't get it deleted.

Try to condense your argument around your central idea and relate it back to the question. Pretend to be an impartial conveyor of other people's ideas without passing moral judgement on them.

Answer (score -8):

This is a rebuttal since the allowable character size in comment is not sufficient.  The problem here lies in the deep unethical issues behind the enslavement of the majority of humanity for the benefit of very few.

The question posed of Greek debt vs US debt is like the following similitude.

Is it less worth while to feed, nurture, and invest in slave A that is sick with chronic illness and likely to die or in slave B that is much bigger and healthier and thus can live much longer for return on investment?

Wait a minute, **slavery is wrong**.  If the poser of the question and the forum in which the question is presented is unaware that slavery is wrong, we need to inform them.

The question posed was about Greece debt but it doesn't matter whether its  Greece, Puerto Rico, Argentina, etc.  We have populations and future generations that are being indebted against their will and without their consent.  It is theft to put  them into debt without their consent.

I should not have to be defending my posted answer like this.  Where is your moral integrity?

Comment: I don't think this is a question about Moral Integrity, but rather moderator astuteness. I'm 100% certain that Phillip or indeed any other mod on this site daily comes across political opinions that he may disagree with, and certainly doesn't delete them all. The reason we delete, is when the answer fundamentally doesn't follow our guidelines. As such your answer didn't specifically answer the question was more tangentially related. As such if you asked a fresh question, about why Greece economic situation is so dire, and presented your answer more neutrally.Then I am sure it wont be deleted.