# community stewardship

Tags: discussion

I have a number of questions/answers which I think are high quality, but which have attracted more down-votes than up votes.  If they are also closed by the usual suspects, should I delete them?

I am asking for people's opinions here.  Community stewardship-wise, is it better to delete high-quality content which angered the prevailing partisans  or is it better for the community to retain the content?

Answer (score 5):

Not everything needs to be deleted just because it's low quality

In the case of closed questions, Low-quality questions will be [Automatcially deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

Downvoted answers will be filtered to the bottom by default, and will be greyed out to show that the community has deemed them low quality.

Answer (score 3):

If you're posting correct information in [an impartial manner](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/a-full-and-objective-description-of-good-faith/3043#3043) you should not remove it just because it attracts partisan down votes. Partisan down-votes are an indication you might be able to do a better job being impartial and you should be self-critical and reflective. However, some people just want to suppress information they find objectionable and it's possible nothing you can do will satisfy them.

Comment: That middle sentence is key. Some downvotes are likely unavoidable for partisan topics, but if the downvotes are overwhelming, the fault is almost certainly yours.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** If content angered any "prevailing partisans" of whatever political direction, it's likely not "high quality content". Nevertheless, individual cases might be worth examining.

---

It's hard to argue against the points raised in this question when it does not point to any any specific questions which you think deserve better.

But I believe that when a question receives downvotes because people disagree with it for partisan reasons, then the question might not actually be a very good question. Good questions should be written from a neutral point of view and avoid pushing any political agendas. So when people find something in the question they object to for political reasons, then the question author didn't do a very good job at that.

But again, I can only guess which questions this meta-question talks about. Maybe the downvotes on them aren't actually justified? Maybe they are justified, but for a completely different reason than I think or you think?

If you would open a new meta-question about one specific question which you think got unjustified down/close/delete votes from the community, then we could take a closer look and analyze how good that specific question really is and how it could be improved.

Comment: My question is not about the content as much as it is about an ethics standard.  If I think the content I created is good quality, should one bother suffering the slings and arrows?  At the other extreme is the approach "if the community can't appreciate it, then it doesn't deserve it."  Partisan winds blow over and inevitably reverse.  This maybe taking it too seriously, but again, I was wondering what would be the advisable personal attitude in such cases.

Comment: @grovkin I think that an advisable personal attitude would be to not be too convinced of the quality of ones own content. The author is usually the worst person to judge the quality of their own work. So just because a person believes that what they wrote is "good quality" doesn't mean that the rest of the world should share that sentiment.

Comment: @Philipp While quite right, the reverse side of the medal is equally true: neither comments nor votes (up *and* down) are a guaranteed quality quality evaluation. The system isn't designed to reliably tell apart the lone rock of wisdom breaking the waves of idiots nor the asinine post getting popular against all odds of reason.

Comment: @Philipp c'mon.  do you really think I can't tell between the times when the quality of what I write is crappy and the times when what write will attract cognitive dissonance downvotes?  According to my profile, I've been here for almost 3 years.  If I haven't learned anything in 3 years, it would be sad.

Comment: BTW, would this question not demonstrate that you may be giving community wisdom too much credit?  I can go and delete it now.  Would that mean that it's not a worthwhile question for the meta site?