# Why was the "What are major reasons behind giving legitimacy to religions & religious practices" question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[What are major reasons behind giving legitimacy to religions & religious practices](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72923/what-are-major-reasons-behind-giving-legitimacy-to-religions-religious-practic)

The close reason states "off-topic" which is defined as:

> The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes as defined in the help center.

I see nothing in that question that can be considered not in [good faith](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3044/12242):

- It appears to be serious.
- The use of the phrase "fairy tales" is wholly defensible, as it cannot be disputed that some of the acts depicted in various religious texts are analogous to things that one would expect to occur in fairy tales.
- It has no highly partisan sources, unless you count the phrase "fairy tales" as such.
- It is well-explained.
- The term "fairy tales" is not a bad or opinionated assertion; it's a comparison.

Comment: When think about it, it still seems as question based on flawed premises. I never have seen priests asking politician to grant him some clout of his legitimacy, but I often see (especially before elections) politicians desperately seeking some legitimacy among priests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because the question is attacking religious beliefs

> However religions are highly similar to hypothetical "fairy tales"

For the question there is no need to bring in the op's belief that religion isn't true.

> which even include many controversial practices such as caste hierarchy, circumcision, polygamy, strict dress codes for women among many disadvantages and restrictions.

Yes some religions include this but that isn't relevant to the question and people can point to religions that don't do what is being complaining about.

The op doesn't even bother to say what is wrong with some of those items when it is consenting adults that want to take part in the activities. And I would question what is wrong with people who prefer to dress conservatively.

Update:

The question has been edited to remove the part about calling religion fairy tails and to change the claims about practices to some religions and it has been reopened.

Comment: It's not my question.

Comment: @IanKemp Sorry I missed that as it is a bit early.

Comment: @IanKemp Corrected the answer.

Comment: 'prefer to dress conservatively' and 'strict dress codes for women' are not equivalent. Wanting to take part is usually the key question as consent vs control or conditioning is not easy to establish for both religious and wider social conventions.

Comment: @Jontia Not every religion has those strict dress codes and even in the ones that do that is how some prefer to dress. We shouldn't be acting like the standards of some religions apply to all.

Comment: That is the major flaw with the question yes, equally we can acknowledge that some practices from some religions are concerning, some rightly banned (FGM). But honestly the question really lacks a focus of a practice that is allowed only because of a religious position to move it from a rant into a real question.

Comment: @Jontia If by major flaw you mean attacking religion and acting like they are all the same then you are correct.  The problem with the question is it is attacking religion and appears to be just pushing personal beliefs.