# Is it ok to consider a question not being too broad if it received good answers?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

During reviewing I met questions like [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18295/why-do-some-countries-intervene-in-other-countries-issues-especially-in-the-fo).

Looking at the question alone, it is clear that it is too broad. However, it received a good answer (7-2 votes) that shows that it is answerable (though the answer is a little novel).

So, I incline not to close it (leave open), since it brought a valuable answer for the site.

**Question:** Is it OK to not consider a question as "too broad" once someone proved that it is answerable by actually providing a good answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why we close questions as too broad is because they are very unlikely to receive answers which fully answer the question. Are the answers which got posted on the question helpful and do they fully answer the question? Then consider your theory that the question is too broad disproved.

Keep in mind, though, [that vote score is not an infallible indicator of answer quality on this website](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/be-more-responsible-with-your-votes?cb=1). There are certain questions which will attract those partisan-pandering answers which will get upvotes no matter how useless they are. If you see such a question with only such answers, vote-to-close before we get even more of them.

But even if the answers deserve their upvotes, look at the answers and check if they really are complete answers. When people write high-quality multi-page answers but still only manage to scratch the surface of the question or cherry-pick one aspect of it, that's an indicator that the question is indeed too broad.